# how to proxy backend requests with the same path?

Tags: nginx

we have an nginx server from which we need to send a request to another server by dns name
the problem is that the user's uid is constantly changing in the address
the request may look like /app/apps/68798-ffgh-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer
or the request may look like /app/apps/55555-555-fghdfhffdfggdf/pool/transfer
we tried to do it like this

```
 location ~ ^/api/apps/(.*)/pool/transfer$ {           
       proxy_pass http://test.bf.fff.com/$request_uri;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;

  }
```

and also tried
rewrite  ^/api/apps/(.*)/pool/transfer$ /(.*)&request_uri?break;
and many other rewrite
how to do it right?

if request/app/apps/68798-ffgh-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer that should be it test.bf.fff.com/app/apps/68798-ffgh-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer and if request with other guid test.bf.fff.com/app/apps/5555-5555-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer

Comment: You need to describe what you are trying to achieve. What does `test.bf.fff.com` expect? You show two example URLs sent to your server, but not what the rewritten URL should look like when sent to `test.bf.fff.com`

Comment: @RichardSmith if request/app/apps/68798-ffgh-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer that should be it test.bf.fff.com/app/apps/68798-ffgh-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer and if request with other guid test.bf.fff.com/app/apps/5555-5555-fghdfhdf/pool/transfer

Comment: It looks like the URL after the domain name is not changing. So you do not need to rewrite anything. Just use `proxy_pass http://test.bf.fff.com;` to pass the URL upstream without changing it.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes,, it works,can you answer and i voting for true